# OneDrive Microsoft Graph error : Token contains invalid signature

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to access the list of files in my OneDrive for Business drive.

I followed the "Code Flow" approach and I got to the point where I already have the token and was able to get my endpoint via `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=mySite`

But when I try to list the files, using `MyEndpoint/_api/v2.0/me/drive/root/children` I get the error:

```
{"error":{"code":"unauthenticated","message":"Token contains invalid signature.","innerError":{"code":"invalidSignature"}}}
```

If I put the full url in the browser I get the JSON result (after authenticating).

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `MyEndpoint/_api/v2.0/me/drive/root/children`, you can use MS Graph REST API to list files in a users OneDrive by sending a GET request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children`.  The request should contain a header with the token with one of the permissions listed at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_children.

Also, the [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) has plenty of OneDrive samples that are worth checking. To see the OneDrive samples click the `show more samples` link.

[image]

Comment: Good to know about the Graph Explorer tool. Thanks!